# Unix - way to see all files that recently got permissions changed

Tags: linux, files, permissions, forensics

What is a way to see all files in a current directory that got recently permissions changed?

Or, another approach to my problem is, what is a way to see how many times a file got permissions changed?

Comment: Check out `auditd` - a Red Hat developed tool for monitoring system changes. This isn't ubiquitous to all unixes, however.

Comment: Some version control systems will track permission changes. I think mercurial does. Some more information about what you trying to do  would probably be relevant.

Comment: Shell history?­­­

Comment: There is none unless you set something up *before* the permission changes. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing forensics (to late to plan for things to be recorded better), then
Use find to find files that were changed after a certain time.

`find «directory_name» -newerct "1 hour ago"`

This uses `-newerXY` command of `find`. X=c to compare `ctime` (change of mode/permission **and any other meta data**) against Y=t time on command line. Use info page of date to get help on time strings.

There is no way to know how many times changes were made, or if it was other meta data that changed, unless you plan ahead, so that more is recorded.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. Whenever a files metadata, and that is much more than just permissions is changed, `ctime` is updated.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Improved answer